# Does all the data in Cache have to be in Primary Memory?

Tags: caching, memory, virtual-memory, tlb

I was studying Virtual Memory, TLB and their relationship with Cache:

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptwjn.png)

And I don't understand the reason behind the last sentence ("Impossible – data not allowed in cache if page is not in memory"), would appreciate if someone could explain me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the operating system swaps out a virtual memory page, all cache entries belonging to the physical page allocated to the virtual page must be flushed. If this was not so, the process for which the physical page is allocated next could get cache hits when it shouldn't - and read data from another process' memory! This is an obvious security hazard, and therefore it is indeed an impossible situation to have data belonging to a swapped-out page in the cache.

However, even if the data was still in the cache, it would be impossible to get a cache hit in such a situation. This is because cached data is generally tagged by its physical address, and, in the absence of a valid virtual-to-physical memory address translation, you would be unable to access the correct cache entry.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, their explanation is not correct. It isn't impossible because "data is not allowed in cache" but because the cache hit couldn't have occured without the translation

Comment: @Afonso Actually, it was me who was wrong on that point. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of TLB and Cache altogether is to minimize the memory lookups and traversing while producing full segmented memory to programs theough page swapping mechanism built into memory management unit itself.

To find exact memory location in page generally cache is checked first and if its missed, tlb along with memory management unit takes care of swapping appropriate pages and make it look like it's there. In reality, any program data resides inside pages given by memory management unit and cannot escape memory management unless you explicitly tell it to utilize hardware features, they all see full virtual memory space as theirs and hardware takes care of address translation.

Givencsource is truth table which states all the possible states and outcome of the states. 
Last two cases, when cache is hit but data is not really present in physical memory, which is impossible states to achieve. Because data is not really there and program is trying to access invalid memory location in any memory segment thus cache hits/miss are not possible and memory exception is thrown by runtime or operating system.

If you want to learn more, start with case studies of advanced micro processors like intel 8086, 80286, 80386 and some of RISC machines to understand how hardware registers are used in software to monitor user programs!

Cheers happy learning!

Edit : 
To give more context to this answer here are some points :

1. OS in conjunction with MMU with special register bits does memory management, neither can work without each other it's joint effort.
2. Swapped data is actually transferred there but application always see full address space from 0x0 to Maximum, it was stated in context of data management.
3. OPs given table is like truth table of all possibilities. A program would never hit cache or tlb, if data does not exist, thus it is marked impossible states, such states are invalid in terms of state machines.

For security reasons programs and their base pointers are always kept in a way that they do not interfere with other programs.

Accessing memory outside is memory violation and there's alot of on top of that mechanism supporting memory access through programming APIs

Comment: Mostly good answer, but a bit ambiguous/incorrect on a few points. 1. Page management is performed by the OS, not the MMU. 2. Swapped data isn't just made to "look like it's there", it is made to *be* there. Or, to maintain your original wording, it's made to look like it *was* there to begin with. 3. A cache hit in the situation described by the OP is not "irrelevant", it is impossible, both because cached data is accessed by its physical address and because having data of a swapped-out page in the cache is a security hazard as it could potentially be read by another process.

Comment: I tried to answer most in normal language as OP might not have all the architectural knowledge and any other reader would get clue about where TLB, MMU and Caches come from. Apart from that, yes there are alot deeper topics that needs much more clean explanation and pre context about how computers works at metal level.